# .htaccess Internal Server Error when i use 2 link structure

Tags: php, .htaccess

Well,

**This is my actual url:**

http://www.domain.com/wix/t1/index.php?username=foyezbd   (this foyezbd is come from variable $username)

**and I re-write it with .htaccess**

```
http://www.domain.com/wix/t1/foyezbd
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wix/t1/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Now I've another page which is **page.php**

so the actual link for this page might be..

```
http://www.domain.com/wix/t1/page.php?username=$username&menu_name=$menu_name
```

so I want to re-write this url with following structure: **(For example $username = foyezbd and $menu_name = About us)**

```
http://www.domain.com/wix/t1/foyezbd/aboutus
```

How can i do this with .htaccess ? I added a new line like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wix/t1/page.php?username=$1 [L]
```

but it says Internal Server Error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a server error because the rule is looping. You don't have conditions to prevent this like you do for the first rule. Additionally, `(.*)` is too general if you want to be able to differentiate between the two:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /wix/t1/page.php?username=$1&menu_name=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /wix/t1/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: let me try it. Let you know shortly.

Comment: Well, It's showing the url which i want. But I lost my CSS Design. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Alex probably because your links are relative, you need to either change your links to absolute URLs (that start with `/`) or add `<base href="/">` to your page headers.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank You so much Mr. Jon Lin.